# techniques to reduce miss penalty in cache optimization

Tags: caching, cpu

By using a Write Buffer it is known that we can reduce the miss penalty in a cache but I can't really grasp that this is true. What is the difference between a read first or write first operation. I mean if we are using a Write buffer, it is said that a read before write decreases the miss penalty. But why would it, isn't it smarter to use write since we are using a write buffer ?I would be glad if we discusssed this issue. Why use a write buffer then if we want to reduce a miss penalty?

regads,

John

Comment: Please use specific examples and questions. For example, what do you refer when you say "What is the difference between a read first or write first operation"? Do you mean between them?

Comment: Its hard to give an example when you dont know how it really works.What I meant was why we do read before writes in order to "reduce miss penalty". When using a write buffer,CPU, (cache)L1,(cache)L2. I can't get why a read before write is better ? why not a write before read ? The topic is abstract dont think I need to provide an example.